# What is the status of Fruitcake elemental?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have found a card called fruitcake elemental.

[image: Fruitcake Elemental Artwork]

This card does that does not appear to be on gatherer, but is on [magiccardinfo.com](http://magiccards.info/query?q=!Fruitcake%20Elemental).  It is a 7/7 green indestructable creature costing: 1{G}{G}.
At the end of your turn it does 7 damage to you, and for 3: you can change control.

Apparently this is a promotional card?  What is it's status?

Comment: Appears to have a silver border. Only black- and white-bordered cards are legal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In typing up the question, I found the answer.   This was a special promotional card given to finishers of the great design search and some of WotC business partners.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105200729/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtgcom/arcana/1240)

There are a number of such cards that exist:
http://magiccards.info/hho/en.html

They appear to be quite expensive, even if they are not playable.

Comment: Wizards also tends to announce these. Here's the 2014 one (not yet on the list you linked): http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/2014-holiday-card-2014-12-02